# Jquery Mobile form validation with AngularJS

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

I am using angularJS for form validation in my Jquery Molbile project because JQM itself does not provide a validation framework. For example consider the following markup:

```
<form ng-app name="form">

    Marital status:
    <select  ng-model="maritalStatus" required>
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="M">Married</option>
        <option value="UM">Unmarried</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

I want green and red borders on valid and invalid states respectively, therefore I have the following CSS:

```
.ng-valid{
border: 1px solid green;
}

.ng-invalid{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The above CSS do not make any visible effect on JQM `<select/>` component.

Here AngularJS seems properly adding the relevant style classes appropriately.

The reason for this issue is JQM re-render the component with some other markup for some reasons. This is not a JQM bug (but may be a very bad way of having the things done!), but this is how JQM works.

What is the best workaround for this problem?

Comment: in jQM you need to add it to `div` wrapping `select` using `.closest('div')` as in this example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vCNkH/

Comment: We do not manually add the valid and invalid classes, they are automatically added and removed by the validation frameworks based on validation states. :-)

Comment: I know, you may need to setup a custom condition to add classes.